# why a hidden file with same name is created when we edit any file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

while working in Ubuntu, when is open a file to edit, say file.txt, after editing a hidden file is created with name "file~" when I close the file
these files are hidden and can be seen if enable see hidden files

Comment: This is not a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your editor is making a backup file just in case you lost your changes due to a program crash.

Answer (score 0):

Editor in Ubuntu keeps the old state of a file, in case you want to rollback to the old state.